# What is the PHP function naming and argument order logic/convention?

Tags: php, programming-languages

Are the functions named, and their arguments ordered randomly in PHP? I find it real hard to remember which function is how, and always find myself referring the manual. What do you do to remember them without having to refer the manual every time?

few examples:
`array_map(callback, array)` but `array_filter(array, callback)`. When dealing with strings `strstr()`, `strpos()` and `substr()` has no underscores but `str_replace()`, `str_pad()` and `str_split()` does. and in most cases, the string is accepted as the first argument but in `explode()` the string is the second argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has quite a few inconsistencies in the internal functions, just something you have to get used to - always have the [function reference](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php) open when coding.

This is an acknowledged problem, but unresolvable without breaking huge amounts of existing code, ie. all of it, as the functions affected are highly used ones for the most part. :-/

Comment: What about when they moved from php4 to php5? werent most of the old scripts broken then? do you know if there are any future revisions planned for php6 maybe? thanks for the ref tip. i normally use the online ref. maybe an offline ref might be faster.

Comment: @Shafee: When they moved from PHP4 to PHP5, there were not *that* many backward incompatible changes, mostly there were changes to the OOP handling, the standard library barely altered.  I do not believe a wide scale sanitisation is on the cards, backward compatibility is a very strong requirement with PHP. I use [offline documentation](http://www.php.net/download-docs.php) mainly for speed, the CHM version on Windows is very useful for quick reference, though lacks up-to-date notes.

Answer (score 0):

I find it nice to have a [bookmark keyword](http://johnbokma.com/firefox/keymarks-explained.html) search on firefox `http://php.net/%s`

So this way I can type in the URL bar: `p function_name`, and firefox automatically opens `http://php.net/function_name`, which is the php function reference manual for the function...

I disagree with Orbling when he says the inconsistency problem is unresolvable... new function aliases could be made to reorganize all of php functions that could be used in new code... for instance having a prefix or some standard way of grouping the functions...

Answer (score 0):

1. English is somewhat inconsistent in the same way. Sir Bernard Shaw once noted that a word that pronounced "fish" may be written in English as "ghote".
2. PHP was grown as any other *natural* language. With bugs, mistakes and inconsistency.
3. Nobody forbids you from writing your own abstraction library with whatever naming and syntax rules you choose.